# How to define the "example" attribute of the swagger generated for a record?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

When I create an API definition by hand in the swagger editor, I can specify an "example" field :

```
components:
  schemas:
    foo:
      required:
        - bar
      type: object
      properties:
        bar:
          type: string
          example: "a custom string example here"
```

In C# I have a record with different attributes. When I launch my application, visual studio automatically generates a swagger, but for each of my fields the "example" attribute is the default one : `"string"`. How can I define this example, directly in my .cs file? I'm looking for something like this:

```
public record Foo(
    /// <swagger.example>
    /// a custom string example here
    /// </swagger.example>
    string Bar
);
```

Thank you in advance for your help, let me know if anything is not clear :)

Comment: Check out [this issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1920).